# its posible configure the property silent print for all populars navigators?

Tags: printing, navigator

lookin for if can posible configure the property silent print for all populars navigators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application) ?
I don't know if scripts work.

Comment: well only said about firefox and iexplore...miss chrome, safari and opera configs