# Printing in client side without print Dialog Box

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, printing, client-side

I want to print a Pdf document which is generated on the server in the client machine without showing a  print dialog box. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Answer is  No, you can’t do silent printing in all browsers,  But on IE there is way to hide print dialog using VBScript.

You can [Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391178/window-print-without-opening-the-print-window) similar question it might help you.

Thanks
Suresh