# Oracle Apex plsql printer name

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I would like to know how we can assign printer in Oracle Apex plsql block or on button click to print without showing the list of available printers.

**I don't like to use `UTL_File` if it involves an external file to print as suggested [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:38012348052).**

Comment: can you clarify where and how the process would run?

Comment: I want to print page on button click but printer selection option not required. Only print command run and printer name should be given in code.

Comment: you could do that in javascript, why would you wanted to be done from the server?

Comment: Let me solution of javascript so I can do that in dynamic action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs

Comment: another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box

Comment: and another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391178/window-print-without-opening-the-print-window

Comment: and one more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application