# How to print without print dialog box in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I already looked; [javascript print without print dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box)

But this opens the popup dialog in chrome.

Or this solution is for Firefox; https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391228/7236291

How can I print silently in chrome? Is there any solution?

Comment: You are unlikely to find an approach that works everywhere as printing is handled by the OS, not the browser.

Comment: I think this would also be a security problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Silent" Printing in a Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application)

Comment: @scott-marcus Does https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider offers a solution to print silently in chrome?

Comment: @mmu36478 Ok, but that's Chrome. now you need to find a solution for every other browser. You are unlikely to find it.

Comment: actually, I'm just looking for Chrome. But couldn't understand the usage of this api.

Comment: A list of third-party solutions is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753, all of which work with Chrome.  The downside is most require a product is installed locally to handle it.