# Printing multiple iframe contents

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

I want to print only the content of multiple iframes in a webpage at once when print button is clicked.

I already tried this code.

```
function printall() {
  window.print();
  for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) {

    window.frames[i].focus();
    window.frames[i].print();
  }
}
```

After adding this code , If i click on print it prints one by one i.e it prints first iframe and again click on print it prints second iframe.

But I want to print all the iframes at once when clicked on print button.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't seem to be possible with Javascript (at least not in an easy or clean way)

- [Select a printer and silently print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656372/select-a-printer-and-silently-print)
- [window.print() - without opening the print window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391178/window-print-without-opening-the-print-window)

But if you tell us a bit more about the desired output there may be another solution like reading the content of every iframe, join it together and then print it.

Comment: Actual problem was printing fractions in a iframe , because it reads content from each iframe and fractions in mathquill woulkd appear like this $\frac{1}{2} (it should print as 1/2) .

Comment: but this has nothing to do with what you asked

Comment: Above mentioned printing fractions problem will come when content of every iframe is read and joined as you mentioned. When I added the above piece of code printing fractions problem was resolved but each iframe prints one after another . I want to print all the iframes at once when clicked on print button.