# change IE and Chrome settings to do a silent printing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

How can i change IE and chrome setting to achieve a silent printing in IE when using this code :

```
function print(){
   window.print();
}

<button onclick="print();">Print</button>
```

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application

Comment: this question has a good answer i am voting not to close it.

Comment: Does somebody know how to do this in IE?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome on the web you can't have the print confirmation dialog not appear, it is a pretty large risk to have this functionality on the open web so that any site could just start print random things to a user's printer.

In Chrome Apps (the installable "native" apps system), it is possible to interface with USB devices such as printers and use lower level PCL to print automatically to the device with no prompt to the user.  Check our sample https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb-label-printer which contains the code that lets you connect to an installed USB label printer and print to it.  Note, this uses a lot of native API's which are not available to web-sites.