# Chrome/firefox api for print to pdf

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I am new to coding and have a scenario where I have a bunch of files(1000+) located on my machine which I want to print as PDF to another folder on my machine.
Are there some Chrome/Firefox APIs available that I can use to achieve this?
I specifically want to use browser's built in feature for printing purposes to print those files.
I know I can use Selenium to automate this solution but if I can get APIs to do the jab, it would be a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to invoke a print on your 1000+ files from a browser and have it "print to PDF" without confirmation on each file. If so, you may be interested in something like "silent printing" (printing without confirmation) but it's always recommended. You can see something about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application