# Printing on a printer with an inbuilt webserver using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I know the title sounds stupid but I don't have any idea how to describe my problem better.

I have a WiFi printer here with a builtin webserver. 
This printer allows uploading of HTML and image files into the internal storage.
From there you can open these pages using the printers IP address and the files path.
There is an example in the technical reference, but this is the only information I have. Unfortunately there is no more documentation about the functionality nor the supported HTML elements I can use for this HTML file.
Unfortunately the sample contains only one printable variable with only a string stored inside.

[Screenshot of the manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnpZa.png)

All I want to do now is to create Input forms which one can fill with information and print afterwards.
I just created a little html file with forms quick and dirty and the printer is able to show them.

[Screenshot of the Internal Webserver with the uploaded HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyJgV.png)

My Javascript skills are not worth mentioning.
I need something like

```
    window.print();
```

without opening the windows print dialog. I need something similar to print directly on this printer by sending the whole HTML site to the webprn.cgi.
I am not sure if it is only possible to print single lines but maybe a whole rendered HTML page.

I have no idea where to start so I hope someone can give me a hint.

Thank you very much!

Bilal

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Silent" Printing in a Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the suggestion doesn't fit my problem. It's not about printing silently through the clients browser which still goes through the print queue/printer driver of the clients system.

I need a solution which prints the whole website by sending everything to the cgi which is located on the server itself. So, I need to print the HTML which is located in the printer on the printer without going through the spooler of the client.