# print without any dialog in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js

friends, i am trying to create print button in my web page and i using chrome to test it, so i don't want to show any dialog, just directly print out the page, but i can do it so if any one know how to do it in chrome please tell me.

## i don't want to show this dialog

[image]

## and this dialog

[image]

## and i don't want to use *"--kiosk-printing"*

Comment: so you want to bypass a users choice of where to print? (the second dialog)? By the way, if you don't want the second dialog to show, use something other than Windows - then you definitely wont get a windows dialog - but I guess you want to force your printing down other peoples throats, not your own?

Comment: I gave a downvote because there was no code or attempt included in the question. Please take a read of https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: ok no meter, if it too hard. thank you friend.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to find a straight forward way to get around this as it could be a security issue if the browsers allow this. However there is some goodness [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application)

Comment: that mean i have no choice right? i have to choose one of them right?

Comment: i just want it to print like an ATM print bill.

Comment: If you are in control of the environment, you can configure the browser. But if it's a site that other people access from their own computer with their choice of browser, you are out of luck. What's the use case for this?

Comment: any way  if i create to use in a computer only