# How to print without opening the print dialog using javascript in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing-web-page

I wanted to print from the Client PC, the document is more secured which should not allow to save in the local. So I want to print directly to the default printer.

Our current problem is that in the print dialog there is an option to save the document in the local "Save as PDF". I need a solution for this:

1. I want to print directly in the printer without showing print dialog.
2. Save As PDF Dialog should not be showed in the print dialog.

Comment: You have no control on the browser or the operating system of the user, and there are countless ways to save a webpage as pdf even without the print dialog

Comment: This is more or less possible on your own machine by [configuring your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application), but you can't access your users' browser configs. Another story is, that a determined user can always save the document, you can't prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, I think you can't do this, because normally, the actions that require to store data in the disk memory without asking anything or to interface with internal or external components (except a part of RAM - in fact, for example, clipboard actions are available) are not supposed to work being forced.