# Print a number without showing Printer preview

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular8

I am looking for a code which will display a number as well as print it without showing Printer Preview.
I already did it but when I want to print the page it appear with Printer preview, and i want to print it directly using POS machine.

Is there anyone know I should solve it?

ts file

```
print(){

window.print();
}
```

html file

```
 <button type="button"  (click) = "createNumber();print();" class="btn btn-primary" >Create Number</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Silent" Printing in a Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application)

Comment: Typically, because of security reasons, this is a browser setting. Imagine, any webpage could just randomly start printing ...

Answer (score 0):

You cann't disable preview print screen for all user.
But if you want to disable it on your computer then read the following website
[Disable Print Preview of Receipts in Chrome](https://www.netohq.com/support/s/article/disable-print-preview-of-receipts-in-chrome)